# How to update total quantity with ajax Laravel 8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, cart

I have my shopping cart, and for adding to cart i'm using ajax. It works, but I don't know how to update total quantity number which located at the header. There is no inputs with a field for selection of quantity, I want it to increase after each pushing button "add to cart" by 1 (with ajax). How can I do that?

CartController:

```
  public function addCart(Request $request, $id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);

    $request = Session::put('cart', $cart);

    Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);

    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

Custom Cart class that contains the main logic:

```
public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

AddToCart button:

```
<div class="product-icon-container">
  <a href="{{ route('basket-add', [ 'id' => $item->id ]) }}" class="scrollOffset btn btn-success mt-2 mb-1">Add to Cart</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mt-2 mb-1">Buy now!</a>
</div>
```

Total quantity in header:

```
<span class="prodcount">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '0' }}</span><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i><span class="basket-text">Cart</span>
```

Simple ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.product-icon-container').find('a.scrollOffset').click(function (event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href')
   });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: Just count Session::get('cart') items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `add()` method, you need to return the result of the updating qty.

```php
public function add($item, $id){
      // your code
    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

and then in your ajax request, it has a `success` function to check the request is successful or not.

```js
$.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
      // onReponseSuccess
      $('.prodcount').text(your_qty)
    },
    error: (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      // handle onReponseError
    }
});
```

Comment: The solution was helped by a person from the Russian-speaking StackOverflow. Here it is: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223651 Your solution did not work, probably I did something wrong. But thanks to you, I figured out another way. I'll show it below in the comments if interested.

Answer (score 0):

My question was completely solved by a user from the Russian-speaking StackOverflow [at the link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223651/ajax-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5/1223797?noredirect=1#comment2142246_1223797).

As an option, you can get a good solution by slightly changing @HEL Mab's code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.product-icon-container').find('a.scrollOffset').click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let totalQty = parseInt($('.prodcount').text());
        $.ajax({

        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
          // onReponseSuccess
          totalQty++;
          $('.prodcount').text(totalQty);
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
          // handle onReponseError
        }
    });
  });
});
```